# Should we add a 'hydrogeology' tag?

Tags: discussion

In common earth science usage, 'hydrology' refers to surface water flow and 'hydrogeology' refers to subsurface flow. We have a 'hydrology' tag but not a 'hydrogeology' tag. Bearing in mind that surface water and groundwater are hydraulically connected, is there value in adding a 'hydrogeology' tag for groundwater and vadose zone flow/transport questions?

Answer (score 3):

There's no point in adding tags in advance of them being used, because they'll get auto-removed.

If you see existing questions for which a new tag would add clarity, and/or would help experts pick the right question to answer, then please do create the tag by adding it to those questions. If you want to be extra-helpful, and give your new tag more chance of surviving and prospering, create a tag wiki excerpt for it too, as soon as you've added the tag to one or more questions.